# How can i get hold on skyscanner API?

Tags: api, skyscanner

I'm building a platform and i would like to use Skyscanner API, however i've been sending emails for the last couple months requesting the API access and no answer until now. Anyone has a better way to communicate with Skyscanner API team? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you matching criteria described at https://partners.skyscanner.net/affiliates/affiliate-products/ ?

Answer (score 3):

Try RapidAPI's SkyScanner integration.